# Database Design own Column or just Query

Tags: database, database-design

I have a spreadsheet with movies, in most countries these movies have the same name, except a few.
That's why I have an extra table for the movie names.

Movie:
id,
[...]

MovieName:
id,
movieID (FK Movie),
name,
country

I n case there are different names, every person should get an overview with all names.
Should I check each time if there are different name for this movie?
Or would an extra Movie column "differentNames" (Bool) be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking about is ***denormalization*** which is moving derivable data from a child table to a parent table.

Denormalization is used to avoid performance impacts, which can be helpful when it's needed.  It has a downside though, which is that you have to do extra work to keep the data consistent between the parent table and the child table.  Since there's extra work to do and more points of failure, there's a risk that these could get out of sync.  Avoiding inconsistent data is one of the main purposes of normalization in the first place.

It's generally acceptable to use denormalization in situations where (a) no other practical options exist to make your code adequately performant, and (b) where the data is more or less read only (i.e. it isn't expected to change, or at least very much).  The basic principles at play here are: 1. Don't pre-optimize and 2. Manage your risk.

Based on this, you can decide whether your situation justifies denormalization.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed two-table solution is usual in case of data localization.

You may also store an original movie country in the `Movie` table and store only different names in `MovieName`. However, you need to maintain this data integrity (unique `movie_id` + `name`) in addition to unique `movie_id` + `country`.